# On enter input box text is being deleted

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that i built using bootstrap, on enter it submits data via ajax, sometimes this works and other times the input box just goes empty and nothing happens.

```
            <form class="form-inline" onsubmit="return Track_User()">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Summoner Name" id="Summoner_Name">
                <select class="form-control" id="Server_Name">
                    <option value="oce">OCE</option>
                    <option value="na">NA</option>
                    <option value="eue">EUE</option>
                    <option value="EUW">EUW</option>
                </select>
              </div> 
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Track</button>
              <div id="Helpful_Output"></div>
            </form>
```

Track_User function

```
function Track_User(){
    // XML request for check summoner name
    Summoner_Name = document.getElementById('Summoner_Name').value;
    Server_Name = document.getElementById('Server_Name').value;

    // Retrieves data about members in the group using ajax
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "check_summoner_name.php?Summoner_Name=" + Summoner_Name + "&Server_Name=" + Server_Name;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            Update_Helpful_Output(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    // Run php script to confirm a few things
    // 1. Do we already know this summoner name + server?
    // 2. If we don't know the summoner, look it up, if false, return error message that summoner name is invalid
    // 3. If summoner name is valid, check if we already know this summoner id + server_name combination
    // 4. If we don't, create a new user
    // 5. -- Finally we redirect to the graph page
}
```

If needed url of development page: http://crew-cut.com.au/bootstrap/loltimeplayed/index.php

Sorry for long url

Comment: have you thought about using jquery? it's the 1 framework that pretty much everyone can agree is really useful and helps make submitting forms via ajax really simple. if you're interested I could help by posting code to do what you need.

Comment: Your HTTP request code looks good to me. Can you show us the code sample for  Update_Helpful_Output() function?

Comment: @dewd submitting ajax via plain JavaScript is as easy as it gets. The problem here is using a form. The OP needs to prevent the default action using `e.preventDefault()`. Adding `e` as an argument to the `Track_user` function

Comment: @Mouser arguably as easy as it gets. i would disagree. there are many things easier in javascript than XHR.

Comment: @dewd Well the ajax code the OP is using is correct. Once you have a good construct for your XHR calls you can reuse it all the time. But I'm a little biased. I like plain JavaScript. I find it not that difficult, while others may, that's true. Programmed an answer in full jQuery today. It's easy.

Comment: @mouser I too am a big fan of plain javascript. i'm not a lover of most frameworks. they're usually overkill, but i can't think of any better way to manipulate the dom than with jquery. ajax isn't dom related, but it's a neat bonus.

Comment: @dewd jQuery does allow for easy DOM manipulation. However `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` made it very easy to manipulate the DOM with plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

```
        <form class="form-inline" onsubmit="Track_User()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Summoner Name" id="Summoner_Name">
            <select class="form-control" id="Server_Name">
                <option value="oce">OCE</option>
                <option value="na">NA</option>
                <option value="eue">EUE</option>
                <option value="EUW">EUW</option>
            </select>
          </div> 
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Track</button>
          <div id="Helpful_Output"></div>
        </form>
```

```js
function Track_User(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // XML request for check summoner name
    Summoner_Name = document.getElementById('Summoner_Name').value;
    Server_Name = document.getElementById('Server_Name').value;

    // Retrieves data about members in the group using ajax
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "check_summoner_name.php?Summoner_Name=" + Summoner_Name + "&Server_Name=" + Server_Name;

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            Update_Helpful_Output(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 404)
        {
             alert("Yeah I'm working, but I returned a 404.")
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();


}

document.querySelector(".form-inline").querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", Track_User, false);
```

```html
            <form class="form-inline" >
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Summoner Name" id="Summoner_Name">
                <select class="form-control" id="Server_Name">
                    <option value="oce">OCE</option>
                    <option value="na">NA</option>
                    <option value="eue">EUE</option>
                    <option value="EUW">EUW</option>
                </select>
              </div> 
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-md">Track</button>
              <div id="Helpful_Output"></div>
            </form>
```

This will do it. No longer submitting via form, but using the track button to start the Ajax call. The problem lay in submitting the form. It just posted the form to nowhere without ever calling the ajax request. Now it does fire the ajax call.

Comment: Thank you that seemed to work, if i try to explain what u did in my own words. Ur using jquery to bind an action to the submit button, when the submit button is clicked (or enter is hit..? (not sure how this takes into account enter)) the function is called. Thanks for the help, just trying to better grasp exactly how you did the fix :)

Comment: @crashkid. this isn't using jquery just plain javascript. the script adds a click event listener to the first element with `.btn` class within the first form with the class `.form-inline`. when `.btn` is clicked, the `Track_User` function is called with the event details: `e` passed into it. you could rename e to somethnig more readable like event or evt, but e is usual. `e.preventDefault()` stops a default form submission, allowing the XHR call. When the call comes back successfully, `Update_Helpful_Output` is called with the data rtnd from the server passed into it.

Comment: @crashkid about the enter, you can change the event listener to listen for form submission: `submit`, rather than a button click. `document.querySelector(".form-inline").querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", Track_User, false);` becomes `document.querySelector(".form-inline").addEventListener("submit", Track_User, false);`

Comment: hey dewd i used mousers code and it worked for enter, which is a bit odd haha, Okay so it isn't javascript at all im just binding a listener to an element. Thanks i understand reasonably well now :)

Comment: @crashkid. This solution is plain JavaScript. No external library is used. JavaScript can bind listeners to DOM-elements.